# REST server avoid robot crawling

Tags: security, rest, web-crawler, restful-authentication

As I know the REST server is stateless server.
Is there a way to make REST server avoid robot crawling/attack?

Your comment welcome

Comment: [`robots.txt`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots_exclusion_standard)?

Comment: Not sure how `stateless` is connected to your question but I'd say that some authentication mechanism (more or less complex depending on your needs) should do the trick

Comment: authentication mechanism in MBAAS, such as parse, the key/authentication mechanism can be cracked

Comment: especially for android java code, REST authentication mechanism is useless